# why the error is not checked in Hex2Bytes of bytes.go?

Tags: dapps, defi, the-dao, audit

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/common/bytes.go

I am looking at the following codes

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/a3829178af6cec64d6def9131b9340a3328cc4fc/common/bytes.go#L79-L82

It ignore the error from the function return. could you please clarify why?